# Keep size the same on all sizes of screens

Tags: html, css, size

I am creating a game called Harvester, and when I either change the size of the browser window or use a different sized screen, my icons look either too short, tall, fat, or skinny. But I want it to stay the same no matter what.

This is what I am using:

```
/*/ Normal:

.example {
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
}

/*/ Larger Screen (What it looks like..)

.example {
width: 46%;
height: 39%;
}
```

I have been using % in hope that it would be different than px. Please Help!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aspect ratio to maintain the appearance of your icons:

```
.example {
    width: 20%; /* whatever you want */
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1; /* adjust this as needed */
}
```

You can read more [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/aspect-ratio/).